# Shadow box only for inner box of container

Tags: css, box-shadow

[image: inside boxshadow]

I am using `box-shadow` but it makes the whole container wrapped with shadow, how can I make a shadow only in the inside (top center) box?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask questions, it'd be helpful to see what you've already tried so that poeple aren't duplicating efforts and your question doesn't get downvoted or flagged.

Comment: Also, have a look at the documentation at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow so that you can learn more about how to use box-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried INSET this will put a shadow on the inside of an element.

```
.shadow{
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #ABABAB,5px 5px 5px 1px #DDDDDD;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #ABABAB,5px 5px 5px 1px #DDDDDD;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #ABABAB,5px 5px 5px 1px #DDDDDD;
-o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #ABABAB,5px 5px 5px 1px #DDDDDD;
}
```